# How to get the ul li values using Javascript

Tags: javascript

i would like to take the value of an li in alert box using javascript.(i.e If i click on PHP it should alert php in alert box). But its showing undefined. Please anyone help on this.

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lang1()
    {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("li").value;
    alert(a);
    }
</script>

<form>
    <ul id="language" onclick="lang1();">
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>ASP</li>
        <li>JAVA</li>
        <li>CQ5</li>
    </ul>     
</form>
```

Answer (score 10):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a `NodeList`, i.e. a **list** of elements. But even of you accessed one element of the list, `li` elements don't have a `value` property (only form control elements have this property).

You can use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)/`.innterText` to access the content of HTML elements.

Now, you want to get the content of the `li` element that was clicked. Since you bound the event handler to the `ul` element, `this` will always refer to the `ul` element inside the event handler.
But you can get the element which triggered the event by accessing the [`target` (or `srcElement` (IE)) property of the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target).

W3C compatible browsers pass the event object as argument to the event handler. In older IE versions the event object is available as global variable, `window.event`. Since you are using inline event handlers there is no difference for you in this case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lang1(event) {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        alert(event.target.innerHTML);
    }
</script>

<form>
    <ul id="language" onclick="lang1(event);">
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>ASP</li>
        <li>JAVA</li>
        <li>CQ5</li>
    </ul>     
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LHGdn/)

I recommend to read [the excellent articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). They describe the different ways of binding event handlers (inline ve, which properties the event object has and the differences between browsers.

Note: Inline event handlers are OK for toy examples, but as soon as your going to do some serious development, use other ways to bind event handlers.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to read all the links  (especially quirksmode) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName() return a node list not an element.
```

You need iterract this node list to get the value of each element
Example

```
var elementsLI = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
var length = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
for(var i = 0; i <= length ; ++i){
alert(elementsLI[i].value);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asks for. It's also incorrect, `li` elements don't have a `value` property.

Comment: What about `<li>Something<li>Something</li></li>` ?

Comment: @NK: That's invalid HTML.

Comment: i am getting 0 as the value in alert box when i click on the li elements. Can you please check

Comment: I said that " Example".
@saminathan: if your DOM is correct , so you can use
 var elementsLI = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
            var length = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
            for(var i = 0; i <= length ; ++i){
            alert(elementsLI[i].innerHTML);// PHP, ASP...
            }

Comment: I think you didn't read the question properly: The OP doesn't want to do anything with the NodeList, he doesn't even want a NodeList. He wants to get the content of the element that was clicked. With this in mind, showing him how to iterate over a NodeList is not very useful for him.