# How to get the ul li values by passing object using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating event handler function for `<li>` for this I need to write onclick function for each li but I want to make event `<ul>`.

For this, I referred this link
[How to get the ul li values using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298928/how-to-get-the-ul-li-values-using-javascript)

But in my case I am using object-oriented flow and I've passed objects to functions but the function is not getting called.
For Ex:

```js
 var handler = {
    showMessage:function(elementObj){
       alert("Function called"); // But this function is not calling
    }
  };
```

```html
<ul id="language" onclick="handler.showMessage({element:this,event:event});">
   <li>PHP</li>
   <li>ASP</li>
   <li>JAVA</li>
   <li>CQ5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @Shubham I've checked the console but no error, no warning, nothing

Comment: @KRY It's working. Your code has nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I am getting alert. Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b14u2kLw/)

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I just saw the code snippet, yes it's working fine. But it's not working at my end

Comment: @KRY Well then you will have to provide more information and provide a reproducible demo.

Comment: something else is going wrong in your codebase. maybe your `handler` is being overwritten or something?

Comment: I just created jsfiddle with my original code and I'm getting console error on that, you can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/8o41h0mf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Works if you place the script "before" =>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your script is being loaded, but `handlers` is being scoped to the script file.  You can fix this by changing:

```
var handler =
```

to:

```
window.handler = {
```

which will make it a property of `window` (ie. will put it into the global scope).